# How to convert var to string[]

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have written a LINQ in C#

```
string etXML = File.ReadAllText("ET_Volume.xml");
string[] allLinesInAFile = etXML.Split('\n');

var possibleElements = from line in allLinesInAFile
                       where !this.IsNode(line)
                       select new { Node = line.Trim() };  

string[] xmlLines = possibleElements.ToArray<string>();
```

The problem is coming at last line, where the following errors arise:

> - `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>` does
>     not contain a definition for `ToArray` and the best extension method
>     overload
>     `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)`
>     has some invalid arguments
> - Instance argument: cannot convert
>     from `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>` to
>     `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>`

What is wrong and what is the way to convert my `var` to a `string[]`?

Comment: You cannot "convert from `var`" because `var` is not a type. `var` is a keyword telling the compiler to infer the static type from the right-hand-side expression. (You probably already knew this, but I wanted to point out the inaccuracy in how you've phrased your question.)

Answer (score 12):

You are creating an anonymous type here:

```
new { Node = line.Trim() }
```

That isn't necessary, just return

```
line.Trim()
```

and you have an `IEnumerable` of `string`. Then your `ToArray` will work:

```
var possibleElements = from line in allLinesInAFile
                       where !this.IsNode(line)
                       select line.Trim();  

string[] xmlLines = possibleElements.ToArray();
```

Another option is:

```
possibleElements.Select(x => x.Node).ToArray();
```

Comment: @SimpleGuy If you want a really deep understanding what LINQ does under the hood (and have much time ;-) ) you shoud take a look at Jon Skeet's excelent [Edulinq series](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq)

Comment: Almost added another answer, but then saw your option using `Select`, which is what I was going to suggest.